# My Kitten has 3 wound

Tags: cats, skin-condition, wound-care

My kitten has 3 wounds 2 under his belly and one between his thigh and belly am not sure how it caused it. I don't think anyone bit it as it is always home I do have another kitten almost same age they play and fight sometimes but  I don't think he would bite him under that area at all as it is very difficult place to bite i feel it could be some allergy or something Does anyone know what it would be and how can I treat it very worried

[image][image]

Comment: If you are worried, you should consult your vet.

Comment: this does not look like bitemarks it is more likely a result of overgrooming.overgrooming can have multiple causes but no matter the cause you will need help from your vet to stop the problem.you can read a bit about overgrooming here https://www.thesprucepets.com/how-to-stop-cat-over-grooming-554052